# Is it possible to avoid static_cast in initializer list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, narrowing

In my code base I often initialize array or vector if bytes using the following the syntax:

```
uint16_t foo = 0xAB, bar = 0xCD

// bytes = { 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD }
std::array<uint8_t, 4> bytes = {{
    foo >> 8,
    foo & 0x00FF,
    bar >> 8,
    bar & 0x00FF
}};
```

I get the following error from clang++:

```
error: non-constant-expression cannot
 be narrowed from type 'int' to 'value_type' (aka 'unsigned char') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
                        foo >> 8,
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The compiler suggest me to add a static_cast to silence the error. I know the cast will work, but I wonder if it is possible to avoid the cast and to keep the syntax as elegant as it is already ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you attempt to add four elements to an array with only three elements?

Comment: this is a typo, sorry.

Comment: As for your problem, *narrowing conversions* (i.e. automatic conversion from a larger type to a smaller type, like e.g. `int` to `unsigned char`) is forbidden in initializer lists. You can't do it without casts.

Comment: So I there is no way to avoid the static cast ?

Comment: a union of uint16_t and uint8_t[2] might help, with appropriate ctor and get functions

Comment: If your sole intent is to make the array definition compile, you can go overboard [and do this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c925a86f2b41670c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no elegant way out of this.

In fact you **must** use a cast. `foo >> 8` &c. are expressions of type `int`, and you must not rely on narrowing conversions in initialiser lists. Only a non-conforming compiler would refrain from issuing a diagnostic with the code you provide.

Comment: Is there a reason why narrowing conversions is forbidden in initializer list ?

Comment: @AMDG - Yes. Narrowing conversions are a risk. Since list initialization was a new feature, and not in any existing codebase, the committee felt it prudent to ban *implicit* narrowing conversions from it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding static_cast a bunch of times, you could do this:

```
template <class ... Ts>
std::array<uint8_t, sizeof...(Ts)> make_char_array(Ts && ... ts) {
    return {{static_cast<uint8_t>(ts)...}};
}
```

And do `auto bytes = make_char_array(...)` with the same arguments as before.

Answer (score 2):

You might create functions:

```
constepxr uint8_t low_byte(uint16_t n) { return n & 0x00FF; }
constepxr uint8_t high_byte(uint16_t n) { return (n >> 8) & 0x00FF; }
```

and then

```
uint16_t foo = 0x0A0B, bar = 0x0C0D;

// bytes = { 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D }
std::array<uint8_t, 4> bytes = {{ high_byte(foo),
                                  low_byte(foo),
                                  high_byte(bar),
                                  low_byte(bar)
}};
```

Comment: Yes, OP seems to need an `auto bytes = serialize_from(foo, bar);`