# Avoid narrowing warning on c-style array creation

Tags: c++

In c++11, the current behavior returns a warning:

```
int arr[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f};
```

Based on the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546220), I was able to create

```
template <class T, class ... Ts>
std::array<T, sizeof...( Ts )> make_non_narrowed_arr(Ts&& ... ts)
{
    return{ { static_cast<T>( ts )... } };
}

auto arr = make_not_narrowed_arr<int>(0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f );
```

But I would like the return to be a classic c-array, but I was not able to achieve it. So far I tried those, but none are compiling.

```
template<class T, class ... Ts>
T[sizeof...( Ts )] make_non_narrowed_arr(Ts&& ... ts) {...};

template<class T, std::size_t N, class ... Ts>
T[N] make_non_narrowed_arr(Ts&& ... ts) {...};

template<class T, class ... Ts>
T* make_non_narrowed_arr(Ts&& ... ts) {...};
```

I want to do the following to have a warning free program, without suppressing them in compiler. So this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094263/create-array-of-chars-avoiding-narrowing) is not a solution for me either.

And I can't change to `std::array` for that specific usage since it need to be use afterward in a c routine that use `T*` only.

**EDIT:** Here a sample (not the exact code 100%) of what I have as code, and what I want to change.

The problem with the function is that based on image type and channel, I perform call to IPP routine, and I provide generic float* as input to the wrapper routine.

```
void threshold(Image img, Image dst, float* th)
{
    // Sanitty ckeck on image, and bla bla...

    // Perform the call to ipp
    IppStatus sts = (IppStatus)0;
    switch(img.nbChan)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            switch(img.type)
            {
                case BYTE:
                {
                    Ipp8u arr[1] = {Th[0] };
                    sts = ippiThreshold_GTVal_8u_C1R(img.data, img.pitch, dst.data, dst.pitch, arr);
                    break;
                }
                case FLOAT:
                {
                    Ipp32f arr[1] = {Th[0] };
                    sts = ippiThreshold_GTVal_32f_C1R(img.data, img.pitch, dst.data, dst.pitch, arr);
                    break;
                }
            }        
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            switch(img.type)
            {
                case BYTE:
                {
                    Ipp8u arr[3] = {Th[0], Th[1], Th[2]};
                    sts = ippiThreshold_GTVal_8u_C3R(img.data, img.pitch, dst.data, dst.pitch, arr);
                    break;
                }
                case FLOAT:
                {
                    Ipp32f arr[3] = {Th[0], Th[1], Th[2]};
                    sts = ippiThreshold_GTVal_32f_C3R(img.data, img.pitch, dst.data, dst.pitch, arr);
                    break;
                }
            } 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"And I can't change to std::array for that specific usage since it need to be use afterward in a c routine that use `T*` only."_ Are you not able to use `std::array<T, N>::data()`?

Comment: Why do you attempt to init integers with float literals?

Comment: You can't directly return C-style arrays from a function. Either use `std::array` or wrap the C-style array in a struct.

Comment: You can pass `std::array` to a C routine. Use `std::array::data()` or even `&arr[0]` would do (but the `.data` version is better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `std::array`. You assert that you're unable to do so as a result of needing to interface with C-style APIs, but that doesn't mean you need to use C-style arrays in your code.

```
//C Header
void do_something(void * arr, size_t size);

//C++ Code
auto arr = make_non_narrowed_array<int>(0.f, 1.f, 2.f);
//If size is meant to be the memory footprint
do_something(arr.data(), sizeof(arr));
//If size is meant to be the number of elements
do_something(arr.data(), arr.size());
```

No need to use a C-style array for this code.

If you're worried about excess boilerplate code, just write a wrapper.

```
template<typename T, size_t N> 
void cpp::do_something(std::array<T, N> const& arr) {
    do_something(arr.data(), arr.size() * sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` isn't correct. the class could have padding.  `arr.size()` or C++20's `std::size(arr)` would be better.

Comment: You are right. I already thought about that. But i will have to do the arr.data() everywhere afterward. But I would like to avoid that if possible. But I agreed with that solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As you're a big fish do feel empowered to change something that's so obviously wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Except the OP has changed it back. Back in my box ;-) and an upvote for good feelings.

Comment: @NathanOliver C-style arrays often require you provide specific byte sizes, not the "element count" provided by `std::array::size()`.

Comment: Right.  Byte size, use `sizeof`.  Element size(count), use `size()`

Comment: @Vuwox That is easily solved by wrapping the C functions.  Add a overload that takes a `std::array` and calls the C function using `data` and the size it needs.  Most likely it will be optimized away so it won't cost you anything at runtime.

Comment: @Xirema That is way too much code for me. The problem is that Im using Intel IPP library in C (old one). And their functions take IppT* array, the std::array::data() could do it, the only issue, is that I have a lot of functions to add the .data() to it.

Comment: @Vuwox Write a wrapper for the IPP Library functions, and do a workspace-wide swap of all references to the IPP Library with your wrapper. There are tools that can make that process easier to do.

Comment: @Xirema I could, but that is a so huge job, there is too much function in that library. At first, I was searching for a simple template to do this, but it seems not straight forward. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Xirema It need some refactoring, but I think I prefer to add the .data() to each call.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after all this discussion, I revisited my problem and tries to make something simple that fill my need, despite is not a super general function.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void no_narrow(float * const in, T(&out)[N])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        out[i] = static_cast<T>( in[i] );
}
```

So that I call it:

```
Ipp8u arr[3];
no_narrow(th, arr);
```